# How to remove margin from QChartView or QChart

Tags: qt, qtcharts

All [Qt Charts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html) seem to have a margin and rounded corners.

[image: Example image with red marked border]

**How to remove both?**

I want the white area to fill the entire dialog. I cannot find any informations in the Qt documentations. I found a screenshot of [one Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-callout-example.html) that does not have this spacing. But I cannot find the code that disables it.

My initialization code looks like this:

```
QPieSeries *series = new QPieSeries();
series->append("Jane", 1);
series->append("Joe", 2);
series->append("Andy", 3);
series->append("Barbara", 4);
series->append("Axel", 5);

QChart *chart = new QChart();
chart->addSeries(series);

QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
chartView->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::red);
chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

QMainWindow window;
window.setCentralWidget(chartView);
window.resize(400, 300);
window.show();
```

Comment: Is the red part of the `QChartView` or part of the `QChart`?  You could try either `ui->pieChartView->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::white)` or `m_pieChart->setMargins(QMargins())`.

Comment: You should do something like this: `m_pieChart->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: @Devopia: `m_pieChart` is now `chart` in the example. Your code works! But i still have rounded borders. If you also know how to remove them, I would accept your answer (if you write one).

Comment: Sure :) something like: `chart->setBackgroundRoundness(0);`

Comment: @Devopia you really should write an anser to this question.
You solved my problem perfectly and I want to close this question (with an answer)!

Comment: @Devopia Thanks; those margins were driving me nuts. I tried like 100 other things but never thought to go through `layout()`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Devopia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5395762/devopia) answerd the question in the comments!

In my example above I needed the following 2 lines of code to remove the red part completely:

```
chart->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
chart->setBackgroundRoundness(0);
```

Comment: I used to do all sorts of bypasses and detours to get rid of that margin. Nice one!

Comment: I've also successfully removed some additional space around the chart with `chart->setMargins({0, 0, 0, 0});`.

Comment: Does not work in QML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357846/630169

Answer (score 6):

At Qt 5.11 this does not work because the `layout()` method `const` (inherited from `QGraphicsWidget`):

```
QGraphicsLayout *QGraphicsWidget::layout() const
```

Furthermore it is not possible to take a copy of this because `QGraphicsLayout` is a base class.

For me this works:

```
chart->setMargins(QMargins(0,0,0,0));
```

Comment: Why would the layout() method being const be a problem, given that it returns a pointer to a non-const QGraphicsLayout? Also, `chart->setMargins()` is not quite the same as `chart->layout()->setContentsMargins()`. Speaking in CSS terms, the former sets the chart's padding, while the latter sets its margins.

Comment: The line `chart->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);` works well with Qt 5. Furthermore Joseph Artsimovich describes perfectly the problem you certainly have.

Comment: This is not right. 1) That method being `const` means it won't modify the `QGraphicsWidget`; but the returned layout itself is not `const` and you can do whatever you want with it, and 2) `setMargins` sets the margins *inside* the rounded border; `layout()->setContentsMargins` is the margins outside that border to the edge of the widget; they're not quite the same.