# How to remove spacing in ChartView?

Tags: qt, qml

Does anyone know how to remove this spacing?

[image]

Those lines below reduce them but not completely remove.

```
margins.top: 0
margins.bottom: 0
margins.left: 0
margins.right: 0
```

**UPDATE**
I added some code. May be this could help to identify my problem. Originally those blank spaces where arrows are located are for legend and tick values. I quess without changing a source code I can do nothing.

`ScopeView.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtCharts 2.1

ChartView {
    id: chartView

    animationOptions: ChartView.NoAnimation
    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeQt
    legend.visible: false

    margins.top: 0
    margins.bottom: 0
    margins.left: 0
    margins.right: 0

    backgroundRoundness: 0

    property bool openGL: true
    onOpenGLChanged: {
        series("signal 1").useOpenGL = openGL;
    }

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisY1
        min: -1
        max: 4
        labelsVisible: false
        tickCount: 3

        color: "transparent"
    }

    ValueAxis {
        id: axisX
        min: 0
        max: 1024

        labelsVisible: false
        tickCount: 4

        color: "transparent"
    }

    LineSeries {
        id: lineSeries1
        name: "signal 1"
        axisX: axisX
        axisY: axisY1
        useOpenGL: chartView.openGL
        color: "#44D77B"
    }

    Timer {
        id: refreshTimer
        interval: 1 / 60 * 1000 // 60 Hz
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            dataSource.update(chartView.series(0));
        }
    }

    function changeSeriesType(type) {
        chartView.removeAllSeries();

        // Create two new series of the correct type. Axis x is the same for both of the series,
        // but the series have their own y-axes to make it possible to control the y-offset
        // of the "signal sources".
        if (type == "line") {
            var series1 = chartView.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, "signal 1",
                                                 axisX, axisY1);
            series1.useOpenGL = chartView.openGL
        } else {
            var series1 = chartView.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeScatter, "signal 1",
                                                 axisX, axisY1);
            series1.markerSize = 2;
            series1.borderColor = "transparent";
            series1.useOpenGL = chartView.openGL
        }
    }

    function createAxis(min, max) {
        // The following creates a ValueAxis object that can be then set as a x or y axis for a series
        return Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.0; import QtCharts 2.0; ValueAxis { min: "
                                  + min + "; max: " + max + " }", chartView);
    }

    function setAnimations(enabled) {
        if (enabled)
            chartView.animationOptions = ChartView.SeriesAnimations;
        else
            chartView.animationOptions = ChartView.NoAnimation;
    }

    function changeRefreshRate(rate) {
        refreshTimer.interval = 1 / Number(rate) * 1000;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE II**

The trick was to use `clip` and put the chartView `into` a rectangle.

```
Rectangle {
    id: canvas
    anchors{
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
        top: parent.top
    }
    height: 250
    color: "#FFFFFF"
    z: propText.z - 1

    clip: true

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: 40

        z: 1

        color: "#FFFFFF"
    }

    GraphView{ //ChartView
        id: graphView
        isTimerRunnig: isRunning
        channelId: channelId
    }
}
```

**and `ChartView aka GraphView`**

```
ChartView {
id: chartView

property alias channelId: dataSource.channelId
property alias isTimerRunnig: refreshTimer.running
property bool openGL: true

antialiasing: !openGL
legend.visible: false

margins.top: 0
margins.bottom: 0
margins.left: 0
margins.right: 0

x: -70
y: 20

width: 360
height: 262

backgroundRoundness: 0


onOpenGLChanged: {
    series("signal 1").useOpenGL = openGL;
}

DataSource {
    id: dataSource
    channelId: channelId
    isPaused: !isTimerRunnig

    onIsPausedChanged: {
        if(isPaused){
            lineSeries1.clear()
        }
    }
}

ValueAxis {
    id: axisY

    //gridVisible: false
    labelsVisible: false
    tickCount: 3

    color: "transparent"
}

ValueAxis {
    id: axisX
    min: 0
    max: 100

    //gridVisible: false
    labelsVisible: false
    tickCount: 4

    color: "transparent"
}

LineSeries {
    id: lineSeries1
    name: "signal 1"
    axisX: axisX
    axisY: axisY
    useOpenGL: chartView.openGL
    color: "#44D77B"
    width: 2
}

Timer {
    id: refreshTimer
    interval: 1 / 25 * 1000 // 25 Hz
    running: isTimerRunnig
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        dataSource.updateFromQML(chartView.series(0), chartView.axisY(chartView.series(0)))
        //dataSource.printChannelId()
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your .qml code?

Comment: @Nulik please check up my update.

Comment: Meanwhile there a relevant [feature request](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66150) at Qt's bug-tracker. Anyone who is interested in "fixing" this on Qt's side, please vote for the feature.

Comment: The problem is connected to the axes. If I set both axes to invisible the margin disappears. It's a first step, albeit not a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible solution 1: `QMargins` property designates the minimum area around the plotting area. Try filling this remaining padding by adjusting the child (plot) itself.

> plotArea : rect The area on the ChartView that is used for drawing
>   series. This is the ChartView rect without the margins.

Possible solution 2: Try to redraw the parent layout after setting the margins. If you are adjusting the margins after the window is created, it may not necessarily refresh the view immediately.

Comment: You know, you are correct thank you. The first approach is the way it works.

Comment: @Doğukan Tunç: Can you provide an example for the solution 1? If I change any of the members of plotArea, the chart becomes corrupted.

Comment: Could You provide and example for 1st solution please?! `plotArea` does not work for me correctly. If I set it to `Qt.rect(0, 0, width, height)` I see no axis there and their labels.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, but couldn't quite understand what the accepted answer meant in solution 1. I found a solution to the problem that worked for me, so I will post it as another answer here.

(I would've liked to know more specifically what the accepted soultion is, but I cannot comment on other people's answers yet.)

My solution is in any case (in addition to setting the margins to 0 as shown in the question, and having the legend and the axes not be visible):

```
ChartView
{
    x: -10
    y: -10

    width: parent.width + 20
    height: parent.height + 20
}
```

Which simply manually moves the plotting area of the Chartview to the top left corner of the parent component and resizes it appropriately. I don't know where the number 10 comes from, but that seems to be the size of the remaining margin. The "real" answer to this question would be how to set that to 0 in a more robust way.

If this answer is the same as the one refered to in the accepted answer, or if that answer is indeed a more robust one, please let me know!

Comment: @Mikhail Is this the same solution you found?

Comment: it was quite a long time ago. Yes that solution was a bit hacky, and  I had to found a new one. The trick was to use `clip`.

Comment: @Mikhail Hacky indeed! How did you use clip? Chartview doesn't have the property, neither does a Window, and putting it inside a rectangle doesn't seem to help either. Sorry to bother you about this old problem, but it really annoys me that I can't quite get it working, though the hacky solution works.

Comment: @Mikhail Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another **trick** is to add this following lines to ChartView

```
anchors { fill: parent; margins: -15 }
margins { right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; top: 0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify how Solution 1 worked for me (Qt 5.12.6):

```
ChartView {
    id: chart

    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    plotArea: Qt.rect(chart.x, chart.y, chart.width, chart.height)

    anchors {
        fill: parent
        margins: 0
    }

    legend.visible: false
    backgroundRoundness: 0
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: That would work only if You do not need axis ticks and labels.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Qt 6.4.0).

QChart chart;

chart.setMargins(QMargins(0, 0, 0, 0));

You can also try negative margins.

Comment: setting negative margins is the simplest answer I have found so far

Answer (score 0):

I had same bug with modal dialog: white border around the dialog and somehow solved it with:

```
contentItem: Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "black"
    border.width: 1
    ...
}
```

Here I solved it by settings margins to zero and wrapping `ChartView` into another `Rectangle` with same background color as setting negative fixed margins is not quite correct as necessary values could be different:

```
Item {
    Rectangle {
        color: "black"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    ChartView {
        id: chart
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true
        margins { top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0 }
//        plotArea: Qt.rect(0, 0, width, height)
        backgroundColor: "black"
        backgroundRoundness: 0
        legend.visible: false
        ...
    }
}
```

Commented out `plotArea: Qt.rect(0, 0, width, height)` might solve the issue as well but it don't: as axis and axis labels disappear in this case for some reason.