# How to Remove Spacing between chartview and it's Plotarea in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qchart, qchartview

1) My requirement is that Plotarea of chartview in Qml should acquire whole space.
2) I don't want spacing between chartview and plotarea grids.
3) For this, i made

```
margins.top: 0
margins.bottom: 0
margins.left: 0
margins.right: 0
```

4) After Doing this, there was still little spacing between grids and chartview.
5) Then i did this, by giving minus values to x,y axis and increasing width and height.

```
Rectangle
{
 width : 400
 height: 200
 clip:true

 ChartView
 {
  height: parent.height+42
  width: parent.width+51
  x:-32
  y:-15
  legend.visible:false
  margins.top: 0
  margins.bottom: 0
  margins.left: 0
  margins.right: 0
 }
   }
```

6) After doing this it got adjusted properly.
7) But when i am chaning Valueaxis(max), then it is again chaing it's position.
8) Valueaxis which is inside chartview, there is min max value, if max=5 then it's 
   displaying properly, if i change max=10 then it's changing its position, on some value's
   it's showing properly, on some it's not

```
ValueAxis
    {
      id:y_axis
      min: 0
      max: 5 // on 5 it's proper, if i change it to 10 grids position is changing
      tickCount: 4
      labelsVisible: false
    }
```

Any Possible Solution ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove spacing? QML ChartView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333187/how-to-remove-spacing-qml-chartview)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do that:

```
ChartView
 {
  height: parent.height+42
  width: parent.width+51
  x:-32
  y:-15
  legend.visible:false
  plotArea: Qt.rect(x, y, width, height)
 }
```

You're forcing your `plotArea` to be at the same position of the `ChartView` and to have same dimensions.
It might probably be `Qt.rect(0, 0, width, height)`. I haven't tried it with your numbers. I'm assuming it's 0, 0 because that's the offset from the `parent` `ChartView`.

Comment: 32 and 15 are heuristic numbers?

Comment: I just copied numbers form the question. Shouldn't affect the plotArea.