# qt chart remove space for title/legend/

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts, qchart

I want to display a QPolarChart in a QChartView.

I won't add a title or a legend anything else than the QPolarChart. 
Unfortunately, when I add my chart I have bit empty white space around the QPolarChart.I guess this is the space for the title and or the legend...

Is there a way to reduce this space?

I already used

```
chart->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
chart->setBackgroundRoundness(0);
```

which helped a bit.

I want to reduce the red margins:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you already followed the guidelines from the answers to the related question: [How to remove margin from QChartView or QChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146502/how-to-remove-margin-from-qchartview-or-qchart)

If you are still not satisfied with the result, you can go one step further and **use negative values** by calling `setContentsMargins` directly on the `chart` object:

```
chart->setContentsMargins(-10, -10, -10, -10);
```

while keeping your `layout` object margins at `0` as you were doing already:

```
chart->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I've done this in the past and it always worked fine, although it's a bit of a hack.

Also, the legend takes up some space so don't forget to hide it if you don't need it.

```
chart->legend()->hide();
```

This is the result you will get after making these changes:

[image: Polar chart with negative margins]

You might try experimenting with negative values other than `-10` to get the desired result.

Comment: My solution in QML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357846/630169